# Help with a JDBC problem

Tags: java

This is a function that returns the minimum doctor ID from a doctor table after accepting a string `s` that is a consultation field in the patient table. For example, if I wrote "cardiology" in the field, then it will return the minimum doctor ID relating to that field.

Also, if a doctor is free or not will be decided by its current status.

By default, the doctor is free, and will be changed to yes after he has been allotted.

There are problems in the SQL statements.

```
public int getDocID(String s)
{
    int did = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:patientDSN");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =
            stat.
            executeQuery
            ("select min(Doc_ID) from Doctor where (Doc_CurrentStatus='No' and Doc_Speciality like '%"
             + s + "'%'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            did = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        System.out.println(did);
        PreparedStatement ps1 =
            con.
            prepareStatement
            ("UPDATE Doctor SET Doc_CurrentStatus='Yes' where Doc_ID = "
             + did + "");
        ps1.executeUpdate();
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return did;
}
```

Comment: You must format it well. What DBMS are you using? What connector? Paste the StackTrace

Answer (score 3):

You have one

> '

quote more than what you need. It's before the last

> "%"

percentage symbol. You must close the last parenthesis too. You may want to take a look at PrepareStatement. Link to [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
   ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(
   "select min(Doc_ID) from Doctor where (
        Doc_CurrentStatus='No' and Doc_Speciality like '%"+s+"%'
      )"
  );
```

You can perform this query:

```
select Doc_ID from Doctor where (Doc_CurrentStatus='No' and Doc_Speciality like '%"+s+"%') ORDER BY Doc_ID ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Can improve peformance.

Comment: Glad to hear. Did you change the query with the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: @aashima, welcome to SO!  If you're happy with this answer as the one that solved your problem -- and it sounds like you are -- you should click the checkmark outline under the vote counter.  That'll mark it as accepted in the system, give santiago 15 rep and give you two rep and a badge.  Everybody wins!

Comment: s should be escaped. Unless it is very obvious that there will be never ever passed untrusted user input. This is especially an issue because of later changes to the surrounding program code which usually do not pay attention to such hidden "must be trustworth" constraints.